# Unable to change APCu size on heroku

Tags: php, caching, heroku, apc, apcu

I wanted to increase apcu cache size in one of my heroku php applications.
I created .user.ini file and added the following line into it as per the instructions given in heroku documentation.

```
 apc.shm_size=64M
```

But when I check phpinfo, I can't see the allocated memory changing. It continues to remain 32M. What part am I doing wrong ?

[image]